# Why does the negation of the minimum possible integer yield itself?

Tags: c, integer, storage, min, twos-complement

So I wrote a little experiment testing underflowing & overflowing, using c and a 64 bit machine. For type int the min/max values are:

```
   int tmax = 2147483647;
   int tmin = -2147483648;
```

I know understand how two's-complement works, that isn't my question.

So I thought, well what happens if I make something negative tmin? That is:

```
   int tmin = -2147483648;
   int negativeTmin = -tmin;
```

**It ends up still being tmin. (That is, negativeTmin will be -2147483648)**

**My question is why is that?** Since positive 2,147,483,648 cannot be represented by int I understand why it isn't that of course, but it seems odd that it doesn't change at all for that makes it the only non-zero int that doesn't change when - is applied to it. I'm not saying I have a better idea of what it should be, I am just curious as to why -tmin == tmin. Does it have something to do with bitwise operations, or how subtraction is done in a computer, or does it default to doing this because what I'm trying to do is undefined, or something else?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int tmax = 2147483647;
   printf("tmax Before: %d\n", tmax);
   tmax++;
   printf("tmax After: %d\n\n", tmax);

   int tmin = -2147483648;
   printf("tmin Before: %d\n", tmin);
   tmin--;
   printf("tmin After: %d\n\n", tmin);

   int tmin2 = -2147483648;
   int negativeTmin = -tmin2;
   printf("negative tmin: %d\n\n", negativeTmin);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> tmax Before: 2147483647
>   tmax After: -2147483648
>
> tmin Before: -2147483648
>   tmin After: 2147483647
>
> negative tmin: -2147483648

Comment: Your "experiments" are involving undefined behavior (signed overflow has one). So reasoning about it has a little value from C perspective.

Comment: You say you understand complement-2 representation. Are you sure? It is the explanation for tmin==-tmin. Think it through in 8bit, for convenience.

Comment: Why aren't you using `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` from `limits.h`?

Comment: Eugene Sh: I see.

Yunnosch: Yes I do, and very shortly after posting this question I came up with what you are talking about (below). However this is not the correct solution, instead I am informed that it is undefined for it's not guaranteed that tmin == -tmin for all machines.

David Bowling: Because I felt like messing with the limits in their 'raw' form I guess you could say.

Comment: What is INT_MAX and INT_MIN on your system? Very relevant info. Also please confirm you're using C99  or later (the behaviour of `-2147483648` changed between C90 and C99, if you have 32-bit ints)

Comment: Posts about why _undefined behavior_ X leads to Y are always a bit of a challenge.  A trouble with why certian code/compiler/platform/phase_of_the_moon does Y provides useful diagnostic info, yet conveys to too many that the particular UB is _expected_ or _consistent_ and leads down the [road to perdition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perdition).

Comment: For even more fun, try `tmin * -1` and `tmin / -1`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you add one to `tmax`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other folks have posted here, technically speaking what you're doing leads to undefined behavior because overflow or underflow of a signed integer in C leads to undefined behavior.

On the other hand, on most Intel systems, an integer overflow or underflow just wraps around the integer value around and sets some processor flag so that future instructions can detect the overflow. On those systems, it's reasonable to ask - why *do* you get T<sub>min</sub> when you compute -T<sub>min</sub>?

In a signed two's complement system, it's good to note that the expression `-x` is equivalent to `~x + 1`. So let's imagine you have T<sub>min</sub>, which looks like this:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

If you compute ~T<sub>min</sub>, you get

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

This happens to be T<sub>max</sub>. If you add one to this, you get a massive ripple carry propagating all the way to the end, yielding

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

which is what we started with. So that's why you're probably seeing T<sub>min</sub> come back.

Another way to see this: you know that T<sub>min</sub> for a signed 32-bit integer is -2<sup>31</sup>. The value of -T<sub>min</sub> should be a value such that T<sub>min</sub> + -T<sub>min</sub> = 0 (mod 2<sup>32</sup>). So which value in the range [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1] happens to have this property? It's -2<sup>31</sup>, which is why T<sub>min</sub> = -T<sub>min</sub>.

So the best answer to your question is probably "technically what you're doing is undefined behavior, but on a reasonable Intel system and a compiler that isn't set to do aggressive optimizations, it comes down to the mechanics of how signed 32-bit integer arithmetic works and how negation is defined."

Answer (score 3):

Your code `int tmin2 = -2147483648; int negativeTmin = -tmin2` introduces undefined behaviour due to integer overflow, so it may yield *any* result. So thinking about any rules why this happens and if it has to do with two's complement makes no sense and is actually wrong.

An integral overflow is *the* example for undefined behaviour, as it is mentioned as example in the standard's definition of "undefined behaviour" ([3.4.3 - undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3)):

> 1 undefined behavior behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous
> program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International
> Standard imposes no requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
> completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
> or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
> terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
> diagnostic message).
>
> 3 EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer
> overflow.

Comment: While it is certainly true that the code exhibits undefined behavior and may have arbitrary results a knowledge of two's complement arithmetic and its overflow behavior is nevertheless frequently useful in debugging, that is back-tracing how an unexpected value may have been generated, and of course turns up in other languages with well-defined two's complement semantics. Therefore I would hesitate to discount the question as UB without further explanation, though the C specifics might perhaps be omitted from it.

Comment: @doynax: if one does experiments, what is the worth of what he finds out if any result can be influenced by "undefined behaviour", i.e. due to compiler or hardware specific abbreviations / short circuits, ... Shouldn't these experiments be done in a range where no overflow occurs?

Comment: While different behavior is possible, such as the optimizer using wider native arithmetic or even trapping implementations, two's complement overflow is still the most common end result. Frankly I find myself imperfectly inferring the prior state of crashed systems based upon limited information more frequently than I could wish. And while I might ultimately might check the assembly to verify the assumptions a wrapped integer is often a valuable clue.

Comment: OTOH, the negative of INT_MIN being itself is not *because of* UB (more like in spite of), so I don't think this really answers the question, it just satisfies the "OMG UB"-crowd.

Comment: @harold Try doing `INT_MIN / -1`

Comment: @M.M I don't see how that is relevant. Dividing by -1 isn't negating, it's dividing by -1.

Comment: In arithmetic, dividing and multiplying by the negative of the identity are the same

Comment: @M.M sure so it would have been nice if dividing by -1 was actually equivalent to negation, but it isn't and we both know it. What I don't know is why you're going off on a tangent here.

Comment: They are equivalent in C though. Depending on the first operand, they either give the same well-defined result in both cases, or undefined behaviour in both cases. This is a good illustration of how UB can give varying results and therefore why it is appropriate to take the "OMG UB" stance.

Comment: @M.M "Why does X happen" is not fully answered with "it isn't guaranteed to happen" aka "OMG UB", that's just fun to know, not an explanation of *why*.

Comment: @harold: nothing wrong about having fun; and nobody will be insured by UB, so no reason for OMG. It's just that doing experiments with uncertain premise is probably worthless.

Answer (score 0):

-X is 2s complement of X
And that is what the hardware does for negation https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_216.html
INT_MIN =  -2147483648 = 0x80000000
2's complement of -2147483648 = 0x80000000

You can calculate 2's complement as flip bits and add 1
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
 Flipping bits of 0x80000000 gives 0x7fffffff. 
0x7fffffff + 1 = 0x80000000 = -2147483648

(gdb) p /x (int)(-2147483648)
   $14 = 0x80000000
   (gdb) p /x (int)-(-2147483648)
   $15 = 0x80000000 
   (gdb) p /x ~(0x80000000)
   $16 = 0x7fffffff
   (gdb) p /x ~(0x80000000) + 1
   $17 = 0x80000000

Answer (score 0):

One further way to think about it.

Data with type `int` is represented with 32 bits. Take tmin = -2147483648, then, of course, -tmin = 2147483648. In two's complement arithmetic, the binary representation for **tmin** is

10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

and, for **-tmin**,

0 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

But only 32 bits are allowed, so the truncation eliminates the most significant bit (in this case, the first zero) and we get

10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

which is **tmin**.

Answer (score -2):

Actually I believe I just realized the answer; as we know 2147483648 cannot be represented by int and so is -2147483648, so when you make -(-2147483648) well that is 2147483648, but that cannot be represented so as described above that becomes -2147483648. Hence why -tmin == tmin.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the issue here is that the value is out of range, but that fact alone doesn't explain why you get back what you started with. That has more to do with the behavior of how signed two's-complement arithmetic works, which I've tried to explain a bit in my answer.

Comment: As you write, with 32-bit `int`, `2147483648` is not an `int` constant, it is a `long` or a `long long` constant, and `-2147483648` is a constant expression of the same type, but since its value fits in type `int`, `int tmin = -2147483648;` does not have cause an overflow, the `long` or `long long` constant expression is just converted to `int`.