# overflow issues in implict conversions?

Tags: c

In my machine size of integer data type  is 4 bytes so maximum value to the positive side is 2147483647 and to the negative side is -2147483648 in case of a signed int. consider the below c program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 2147483648;
    int  b = -2147483649;

    printf("%d",a);
    printf("\n%d",b);



    return 0;
}
```

output:
-2147483647
2147483647

why a is implicitly getting converted to -2147483648 and b implicitly getting converted to 2147483647? and why I am getting only for line number 2 the below- given warning

"overflow in implicit constant conversion(-woverflow)"

Comment: This can be explained by understanding how 2's complement encoding works. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Comment: overflow and underflow of signed integer are undefined.

Comment: 1.  integer overflow is undefined behavior.  You should not expect consistent results from these assignments.  2.  Your results 1&2 seem intuitive to me (if I were going to define the desired behavior, that's what it would be).  I'm not sure about the missing warning, though.  That seems *undesirable* :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the negation of the minimum possible integer yield itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089640/why-does-the-negation-of-the-minimum-possible-integer-yield-itself)

Comment: @zzyzx There's no UB in this code. You should expect consistent results if rerunning the code on the same implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you want is enabled in GCC by `-pedantic`. In Code Blocks go over to Settings, Compiler and find "Enable warnings demanded by strict ISO C". Turn that on.

Comment: It drives me nuts what C compilers consider "pedantic" in terms of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your case is integer overflow which causes undefined behaviour.

From C Committee draft (N1570)

> **3.4.3**
>   1 undefined behaviour
>   behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.
>   2 NOTE: **Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results**, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
>   3 EXAMPLE: **An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.**